# @IsExpandable for Xpages

Tags: xpages

I have a requirement to hide column headers on a categorized view if all of the categories are collapsed.  I've seen many posts on how to expand or collapse all but not how to tell if even a single one is expanded.  Any ideas?

Comment: My guess here is that you will have to do this through clientside javascript/jQuery. Use your browser tools, and see if the headers have different attributes depending on whether they are expanded or not.  If so, then you can hide them using javascript in the onclick of the twistie (assuming there is one).

Comment: Steve's suggestion may be the most expedient course. There are methods if you get the data source, I think, to iterate over the rows and check expanded state, but the hassle involved would be greater than via CSJS.